# changing Jpanels

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, jbutton

i'm trying to make it display one JPanel and remove the other depended on which timer is off in java. here is the snip it of code. mainMenu and pongField are the JPanels and this is inside a timer that acts every millisecond;

```
if (SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, pongField) != null){
    if (!pongField.getTimer().isRunning())
    {
        mainMenu = new MainMenu(screenX, screenY, myColor, background, contentPane);
        contentPane.remove(pongField);
    }}
    if (SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, mainMenu) != null){
    if (!mainMenu.getTimer().isRunning())
    {
        switch(mainMenu.getButton())
        {
        case 1:
            pongField = new PongField(screenX, screenY, 0, moderator, player1UpControl, player2UpControl, player1DownControl, player2DownControl, myColor, background, contentPane, speed);
            mainMenu.setButton(0);
            contentPane.remove(mainMenu);
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:

            break;
        }
    }}
```

let me be a little more specific.
I am trying to make Pong, and one JPanel is the actual game while the other is the main menu. if the game ends the timer stops and if i press a button on the main Menu the timer stops and set getButton() to a number depending on which is pressed. for example if button single player is pressed it creates the game and gets rid of the current Jpanel. but if the game ends it get rid of the current JPanel and displays the main menu. Also each JPanel when created set it's own bounds, background color, and adds itself to the JFrame.

The problem is when i run it and the game ends it doesn't change back unless i minimize it and bring it back up but then the button won't work. here is the code for MainMenu. PongField's code is too long but i think i summed up what it did good enough but i can post it too if you want.

public class MainMenu extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
//JButtons
private JButton singleJButton, multiJButton, settingsJButton, exitJButton;

//timer if game is still on
private Timer runningTimer;

//JLabel for title
private JLabel titleJLabel;

//screen size
int screenX, screenY;

//color of text and background
private Color myColor, background;

//Container of the JFrame
private Container contentPane;

//which button was clicked
private int buttonPressed;

public MainMenu(int x, int y, Color myC, Color backg, Container contentP)
{
    super();

    //Initialize all given variables
    screenX = x;
    screenY = y;
    myColor = myC;
    background = backg;
    contentPane = contentP;


    setBounds(0,0,screenX,screenY);
    setBackground(background);
    contentPane.add(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();

    singleJButton = new JButton();
    singleJButton.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 50);
    singleJButton.setText("Single Player");
    singleJButton.setFocusable(false);
    contentPane.add(singleJButton);
    singleJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {singleJButtonAction(event);}});

    runningTimer = new Timer( 30, new ActionListener() 
    {public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {}});

    runningTimer.start();
}

public Timer getTimer()
{
    return runningTimer;
}

public int getButton()
{
    return buttonPressed;
}

public void setButton(int val)
{
    buttonPressed = val;
}

private void singleJButtonAction(ActionEvent e)
{
    runningTimer.stop();
    buttonPressed = 1;
}

//make this panel have focus
public void focus()
{
    requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the panels not just setVisible(true/false)?

Comment: yes, because i want to reset all the variables in the JPanel everytime i show a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What, is it not working? I'm just guessing because you don't say.

The first thing I see if you're creating and removing panes dynamically. It would be more efficient to just hide them. Of course, I don't know what your layout looks like. The other option is to just construct them on startup with all your other GUI stuff and go ahead and add and remove them, but don't recreate them based on the timer. Just show them and hide them as needed. Like this:

```
mainMenu.setVisible( true );
mainMenu.setVisible( false );
```

Every millisecond if also pretty fast. I look at ratcheting down, to say one second or so. Of course, it depends on what you're doing.

HTH

Comment: i added more to my question to explain

Comment: i used setVisible for the mainmenu but i want i already had for pongField and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

I still have problem understanding what your question is?

One thing that seems to be missing in the code is where you add the mainMenu and pongField you create. You remove them from the contentPane by `contentPane.remove(pongField);` and `contentPane.remove(mainMenu);` is that your problem?

Comment: no as i said " Also each JPanel when created set it's own bounds, background color, and adds itself to the JFrame." inside the consturctor of each JPanel it adds it's self to the Jframe. for example on in the second codes constructor i put this "contentPane.add(this);"